# How do you filter a SharePoint list based on columns with blank values?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, list-view, sharepoint-online, fast-for-sharepoint, item

I want to create a view whereby it does not include any items where the 'next review date' are not blank. In other words, only include items which have this field populated.

How can I filter my view for this blank criterion in SharePoint? It does seem to recognized `[]` or `[blank]` or `""` in the criteria box.

Comment: Thank you .. this solution work great!! Thank you form the bottom of my heart!

Comment: This does not work with multiple lines of text.

Answer (score 28):

Create a list view and set the filter; where date time column is not empty (see below)

[image]

Comment: does this work for lookup columns?

Comment: @egidiocs yes it did work for lookup columns

Answer (score 2):

the view's filter will be:
'next review date' in not equal to [leave it blank - don't write anything]